# How to create a Persian file.txt and then explode it?

Tags: php, string, unicode, character-encoding, explode

I have a lot Persian text and I want explode it, I store my text in a `file.txt`. (So i have a file.text containing Persian text). Now my problem is charset. When i save the text into `file.text`, it give me a error:

> This file contains characters in Unicode format which will be lost if you save this file as a ANSI encoded text file. To keep the Unicode information, click cancel below and then select one of the Unicode options from the Encoding drop down list. Continue?

I continue. Now when I open `file.text` all characters are fine, and when explode it, all characters crash.

**Note:** when I put text in a php variable, all thing is fine, in fact my problem is with file.text.

What should I do ?

**My code:** *(for explode)*

```
$text=file_get_contents('file.txt');
$var = explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($var  as $sentence) {
        echo $sentence.'<br>';  // or save into databse
    }
```

Comment: is your generated html page with utf-8 content-type header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to save the text file in the UTF-8 encoding. (Use UTF-8 for your HTML output and database connection as well, to match.)

If you save a file as the encoding that Microsoft misleadingly call “Unicode” you will actually get UTF-16LE, a two-byte, non-ASCII-compatible encoding that is generally a bad idea.

PHP's basic string ops like `explode` operate on a byte basis, so if you split a UTF-16 on a single `\n` byte you will end up splitting up a two-byte character in the middle and messing up the byte order of the following string (and every alternate string).

Use a decent text editor that gives you the possibility to save as UTF-8 without BOM, because Notepad will give you a UTF-8-faux-BOM at the start of the file, meaning that when you read it in PHP your first line (but none of the other lines) will have a U+FEFF Byte Order Mark character at the start of the string, causing widespread conclusion.

Prefer a text editor that saves in BOM-free-UTF-8 by default. Notepad's preference for ANSI, UTF-16LE, and faux-BOMs makes it a pretty terrible choice of editor for the web.

Comment: aha i see, i will check it

Comment: Worked correctly, I use 'encode in UTF-8 without BOM' (using notpad++). Thanks pal.